# How to Install an Earlier Version of libsvn-java

Tags: subclipse

I installed the latest version of Eclipse Neon in Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. When I attempted to create a PHP project I got this error:

Failed to load JavaHL Library.
These are the errors that were encountered:
no libsvnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl-1 in java.library.path
no svnjavahl in java.library.path
java.library.path = /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jni:/lib:/usr/lib

So I attempted to install JavaHL follow the instructions at:
http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL

In Eclipse: Help => Installation Details I see I have Subclipse version 1.10.13. According that web page I need to install SVN/JavaHL version 1.8.x. When I follow the directions farther down that page and execute the command:

sudo apt-get install libsvn-java

what is installed is version 1.9.3-2ubuntu1. How can I install version 1.8.x?

I attempted to install Subclipse version 1.12.x by pasting the URL: http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.12.x

In Eclipse: Help => Install New Software => Work with field, after removing both Subclipse and SVNKit. But the versions it was going to install was still Subclipse 1.10.13 and SVNKit Library 1.8.12

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the right thing.  The Subclipse version is the same because it is not possible to host both the 1.8.x and 1.9.x version of the JavaHL plugin on the same site and there is otherwise no difference in the versions.

That said, since you have 1.9.x available you should just move on to the new location and version of Subclipse that only supports 1.9.x.  The project has moved here:

https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse

Information on installation and JavaHL is in the wiki.

Note that other than a few small bug fixes that have been released, it is not much different than the version that was on tigris.  That said, that version is dead and will not receive any more updates so it makes sense to move to this version now.